# How to remove register completely from the authetication in my laravel project?

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication

So i wanted to make a login for admin only using the laravel authentication. So i wanted to remove the register so that only admins can login and no other people can register from outside and i removed all files but now i want to remove it from the routes as well so can anyone tell me from where i can remove register route and from where can i can the login URL name to /admin. Is there a way i can change it because in routes there is only Auth::routes() and i guess there must be somewhere else where all the routing for authentication is located.

Comment: `Auth::routes(['register' => false]);`

Comment: now how can i change the default authentication login route from /login to /admin?

Comment: Explicitly define the routes. Delete auth routes. Make route named admin and point to login controller. Make a logiut route as well.